# Is this a good implementation of a custom locking mechanism?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a task where I need to implement a locking mechanism. This is what I have so far. Basically I need the lock method to try to acquire a lock and return true if lock was acquired and false otherwise. And the unlock method which tries to release the lock, and return true if successful, false otherwise.

Is this a proper way to implement this, or can it be done otherwise? What improvements can be added to this code, or in what ways can it be modified ?

Thanks in advance,

Andrei

```
private Long threadId;

private int lockHolds;

public synchronized boolean lock(long waitTime) throws DataStoreException {
    if (lockHolds == 0) {
        doLock(waitTime);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private synchronized void doLock(long waitTime) throws DataStoreException {
    if (lockHolds == 0) {
        lockHolds++;
        this.threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    } else if (lockHolds > 0 && this.threadId == Thread.currentThread().getId()) {
        lockHolds++;
    } else {
        try {
            wait(waitTime);
            lockHolds++;
            this.threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public synchronized boolean unlock() {
    if (lockHolds == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    lockHolds--;

    if (lockHolds == 0) {
        notify();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Using `synchronized` to _implement_ locking is kind of self-defeating, isn't it?

Comment: Reviews of working code are better fitted on CodeReview (codereview.stackexchange.com) than Stackoverflow.

Comment: Why don't you use a ReentrantLock as the lock you wish to test and remove the synchronized keyword.

Answer (score 4):

1. This is wrong:

   ```
   wait(waitTime);
   lockHolds++;
   this.threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
   ```

You just wait it out, then steal the lock from the currently owning thread. The thread is probably in the middle of its critical section, therefore you allow concurrent access to the critical section.

2. `wait` must always be used in a loop that repeatedly tests for the condition being awaited, to defend from spurious wakeups.
3. The `lock()` method only checks the `lockHolds` variable and refuses to proceed if it's non-zero, thus preventing the reentrant behavior of the lock.
4. Your `unlock` method is wrong because any thread can call it and release another thread's lock.

Although I'm not familiar with your requirements, for me it would be very odd to request a custom lock implementation but allow it to rely on both the built-in lock implementation and the built-in wait-notify mechanisms. But that part is up to you.